# I am trying to get input from users that is case insensitive with two key words. How can I get input that is case insensitive with two major keywords?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get input from users that is case insensitive and has two key words but its refusing .How can I make it automatic that the user enters enters the information in any letter case? My assignment was to make the user answer a riddle in three tries and if the user loses a message is shown .So this is what I so far have.

```
 print("There are two sisters. The former is produced by the latter while the latter produces the former. Who are these two sisters?")
print("YOU HAVE ONLY THREE TRIES OR YOU BECOME A ROTTEN EGG. Just kidding.")
answer = "seed and fruit"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != answer and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter your answer: ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("YOU LOSE. Your a rotten egg, just kidding. The answer is seed and fruit.")
else:
    print("YOU WIN. Turns out your no rotten egg.")
```

I want to make the input the user enters text **insensitive** with **seed and fruit** as the major **key words**.How can I solve this?